# Make table and text appear in the same page

Tags: tables

I have this page with section Appendix defined like this

```
\section{Appendix}
```

Then I start the table. But somehow the table appears in the next page. The table is small enough to fit in the same page.

I tried with

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] 
....................
\end{table}
```

But it doesn't seem to help

Comment: If you don't have a caption to accompany the table, you can just use `\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{..} ... \end{tabular} \end{center}`... no need for a *floating* `table` environment.

Comment: Does your `table` have a `\caption`?

Answer (score 2):

Some bad example for tables, but nice to show the floating around of table at the 'wrong' position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}


\appendix
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline

\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Not Floating around table}
\end{center}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Floating around table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note**

Please look a the screen shot: Although defined as 2nd table (Table 2) it is positioned as 1st one and vice versa.